# Typescript: scale up or down an reciepe object?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have some reciepes in my app and want to scale them up or down to a calorie amount.

My reciepe object looks like this:

```js
{
  title: "some title",
  calories: 700,
  fat: 20,
  carbs: 10,
  protein: 40,
  //...
  ingredient: [
    {
      name: "sugar",
      amount: 20,
      measurement: "g"
    },
    {
      name: "banana",
      amount: 1,
      measurement: "piece"
    }
  ]
}
```

**My question:** Whats the best way to scale this up to 1000 calories or scale it down to for example 400 calories?

Is it possible to do a classic "3 set" with the whole object: At first calculate 100 calories of this reciepe and then calculate a 400, 500 or 1000 calories with all the properties?

Thanks for help :)

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Please clarify it to avoid downvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be working:

```
interface Ingredient {
    name: string;
    amount: number;
    measurement: "g" | "piece";
}

interface Reciepe {
    title: string;
    calories: number;
    fat: number;
    carbs: number;
    protein: number;
    ingredient: Ingredient[];
}

function scale(reciepe: Reciepe, calories: number): Reciepe {
    const ratio = calories / reciepe.calories;
    const scaled = Object.assign({}, reciepe);

    scaled.calories = calories;
    scaled.fat = reciepe.fat * ratio;
    scaled.carbs = reciepe.carbs * ratio;
    scaled.protein = reciepe.protein * ratio;

    for (let i = 0; i < reciepe.ingredient.length; i++) {
        scaled.ingredient[i].amount = reciepe.ingredient[i].amount * ratio;
    }

    return scaled;
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20Ingredient%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20amount%3A%20number%3B%0A%20%20%20%20measurement%3A%20%22g%22%20%7C%20%22piece%22%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20Reciepe%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20title%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20calories%3A%20number%3B%0A%20%20%20%20fat%3A%20number%3B%0A%20%20%20%20carbs%3A%20number%3B%0A%20%20%20%20protein%3A%20number%3B%0A%20%20%20%20ingredient%3A%20Ingredient%5B%5D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20scale(reciepe%3A%20Reciepe%2C%20calories%3A%20number)%3A%20Reciepe%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20const%20ratio%20%3D%20calories%20%2F%20reciepe.calories%3B%0A%20%20%20%20const%20scaled%20%3D%20Object.assign(%7B%7D%2C%20reciepe)%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20scaled.calories%20%3D%20calories%3B%0A%20%20%20%20scaled.fat%20%3D%20reciepe.fat%20*%20ratio%3B%0A%20%20%20%20scaled.carbs%20%3D%20reciepe.carbs%20*%20ratio%3B%0A%20%20%20%20scaled.protein%20%3D%20reciepe.protein%20*%20ratio%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20for%20(let%20i%20%3D%200%3B%20i%20%3C%20reciepe.ingredient.length%3B%20i%2B%2B)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20scaled.ingredient%5Bi%5D.amount%20%3D%20reciepe.ingredient%5Bi%5D.amount%20*%20ratio%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20return%20scaled%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20reciepe%3A%20Reciepe%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20title%3A%20%22some%20title%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20calories%3A%20700%2C%0A%20%20%20%20fat%3A%2020%2C%0A%20%20%20%20carbs%3A%2010%2C%0A%20%20%20%20protein%3A%2040%2C%0A%20%20%20%20ingredient%3A%20%5B%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%22sugar%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20amount%3A%2020%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20measurement%3A%20%22g%22%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%22banana%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20amount%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20measurement%3A%20%22piece%22%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%5D%0A%7D%0A))

Answer (score 1):

Say you have your recipe like so:

```
const recipe = {
  title: "some title",
  calories: 700,
  fat: 20,
  carbs: 10,
  protein: 40,
  //...
  ingredient: [
    {
      name: "sugar",
      amount: 20,
      measurement: "g"
    },
    {
      name: "banana",
      amount: 1,
      measurement: "piece"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Step one:** Figure out the scaling factor:

```
const desiredCalorieCount = 1000;
const scalingFactor = desiredCalorieCount / recipe.calories
```

**Step two:** Make a function to multiply every number by the scaling factor.

```
function transformObjectByScalingFactor(obj: any) {
    for (const key in obj) {
        if (typeof recipe[key] !== "number") { continue; }

        recipe[key] *= scalingFactor;
    } 
}
```

**Step three:** Call the function a lot.

```
transformObjectByScalingFactor(recipe);
recipe.ingredient.map(x => transformObjectByScalingFactor(x))
```

**Optional step 4:** Make the function recursive so you only have to call it once.

Comment: Looks really promising. I will try that today! Thanks!